# How can I get this relative path working in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, relative-path

I have a folder structure like this

- lots of folders

  - another subfolder

    - _includes

      - getStatisticsTable.php
    - _templates

      - StatisticsWrapper.html

In `StatisticsWrapper.html` I'm using jQuery's `.get()` function to get some external data that should be made using `getStatisticsTable.php` but when I use the relative path:
"`../_includes/getStatisticsTable.php`" it doesn't work.

My guess was that it's not working because the file `StatisticsWrapper.html` is being included by another file in a lower folder, so I tried making the path relative to that folder but it's not working.

From where should I search for the `getStatisticsTable.php`? Is there an easy way to find out where the file is searching from?

Comment: are you including StatisticsWrapper.html from somewhere else?

Comment: yes, but that file should be included by another file, should I backtrack all the way?

Comment: use an absolute path as @Michiel said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try discovering your location using `document.location.href`